# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'a','a','a','a','a','desc')' at line 1
```

my query is

```
mysql_query("insert into
room_booking(name,address,type,roomNo,arrival,arrivaldate,departure,
             departuredate,identity,email,adult,children,contact,
             extraroom,laundry,parking,spa,tennis,swimming,description)         
values('$nm','$add','$typ','$roomno','$arrv','$arrivaldate',
       '$departure','$dDate','$idt','$emailid','$adul','$child',
       '$cont','$extra,'100','100','100','100','100','$desc')");
```

Comment: can anybody suggest a solution for this?

Comment: `...t','$extra,'100','1...` <-- note the missing `'` after `$extra`. You should _really_ read up on SQL injection and the deprecated `mysql_*` API though.

Comment: thank you Joachim Isaksson...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are missing `"'"` in `'$extra`, it is a simple error just see your syntax

Answer (score 2):

missing quote near '$extra, use below query

```
mysql_query("insert into
room_booking(name,address,type,roomNo,arrival,arrivaldate,departure,
             departuredate,identity,email,adult,children,contact,
             extraroom,laundry,parking,spa,tennis,swimming,description)         
values('$nm','$add','$typ','$roomno','$arrv','$arrivaldate',
       '$departure','$dDate','$idt','$emailid','$adul','$child',
       '$cont','$extra','100','100','100','100','100','$desc')");
```

Answer (score 1):

you are just missing a quote. Try this:

```
mysql_query(insert into room_booking(name,address,type,roomNo,arrival,arrivaldate,departure,departuredate,identity,email,adult,children,contact,extraroom,laundry,parking,spa,tennis,swimming,description) values('$nm','$add','$typ','$roomno','$arrv','$arrivaldate','$departure','$dDate','$idt','$emailid','$adul','$child','$cont','$extra','100','100','100','100','100','$desc')");
```

Answer (score 1):

missing quote ' on variable $extra

```
  mysql_query("insert into room_booking(name,address,type,roomNo,arrival,arrivaldate,departure,
              departuredate,identity,email,adult,children,contact,
              extraroom,laundry,parking,spa,tennis,swimming,description)         

             values('$nm','$add','$typ','$roomno','$arrv','$arrivaldate',
                    '$departure','$dDate','$idt','$emailid','$adul','$child',
                    '$cont','$extra','100','100','100','100','100','$desc')");
```